# How to inline code pseudo css class :hover on react material-ui element?

Tags: css, reactjs, hover

This is a coding style question. How to inline-code pseudo css class :hover on react material-ui element?

Something like this?

> <Paper style={{"&hover": { "background-color": "black" } }>

The problem is that the style prop doesnt seem to like this.

I want the paper element to turn black on mouse hover. &hover is called a css pseudo class.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I clarified the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug around the internet some more

https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/

```
<Paper sx={{
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
}}>
</Paper>
```